# Интерфейс IComparable

Tags: c#

```
public interface IComparable
{
    int CompareTo(object o);
}

class Person : IComparable<Person>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int CompareTo(Person p)
    {
        return this.Name.CompareTo(p.Name);
    }
}
```

Не могу разобраться, что происходит в коде. Определяется метод  CompareTo() с входящим параметром типа Person. Метод возвращает ... что(число - это понятно)? Просьба описать.

Comment: если < 0 то первое меньше, если =0 то объекты равны, если > 0 то первый объект больше.

Comment: в данном коде используется не [`IComparable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx), а [`IComparable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx). [Описание с примером в MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/43hc6wht(v=vs.110).aspx)